# onScanCompleted() callback from the MediaScanner returns an null URI if the path is from getFilesDir(). Is the behavior intended?

Tags: android

I have discovered a little strange behavior while working with the `MediaScanner`

If the path of file I want to scan is from `getFilesDir()` which is: `/data/user/0/..` the `onScanCompleted()` will return an non-null `path` but a null `Uri`, while If the path is something like `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyDirectory`both`path` and `uri` will be non-null.

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()}, null, this);

public void onScanCompleted(final String path, final Uri uri) {


}
```

I'm just wondering if this is intended behavior? I have tested it on a emulator running `Pixel 2 API 24 Nougat`

Comment: Since the contents of `getFilesDir()` are private to your app, I doubt that the media scanner can read them.

Comment: @CommonsWare that's what I suspected too but wanted to confirm it. But its then strange that a `path` is still returned but `uri` is not